# Fetch the first column data only

Tags: laravel

I use this code to get the average of database column data using foreach. The average was calculated but gave the output in multiples of the column calculated. I just need a single output. Some please help.

```
@foreach($results as $result)

    @if($result->student_id == $id)

        {{ $result->where('student_id', '=', $id)->average('mark') }}

    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what you're trying to do/get?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, this change will help you:

```
@foreach($results as $result)

    @if($result->student_id == $id)

        {{ $result->where('student_id', '=', $id)->average('mark')->first() }}

    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: I have tried this before but return this error - Call to a member function first() on float